# Android DB List Adapters: multiple columns, aligned?

Tags: android

Ok I can't find a sample anywhere.

I've done the notepad tutorial on Google's Android site, but I would like to know how to add more fields to the list, in columns. At the moment I can add the columns no problem, but they're not aligned like you would a normal table on the layout:

```
john smith
heinrich cilliers
will peck
```

I would like the first names and last names aligned proportionately, as you would in an html table.

It works if I use a constant value for the layout_width parameter (100dip etc), but I would prefer to use a relative percentage. However it's becoming clear that each row is on it's own, and does not know how to alighn itself with the row above.

Any pointers?

UPDATE: I've reached an experienced Android developer which advised me to use WeightSum, which brings me closer, but vertical alignment is stil not happening:

[image: Alignment Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I think therefor you have to extend the ListAdapter. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: Thanks but your link does not show how to extend the ListAdapter though. It does give a sample on how to show two fields but one below the other. I want to display it in normal columns. Like a spread sheet.